# Vue.js VeeValidate how to prevent validation until user finished the input

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using [VeeValidate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/) to validate user's inputs in my vue component.
The problem is it is validate the fields immediately when user start to input the data in to field.

[image]

In here even I didn't finish the enter my email it says invalid email.

How can I prevent this? **I want to display error message after the user focus out from the field.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
data-vv-validate-on="blur"
```

to the component attributes. I'd link to the documentation, but I actually didn't find any mention of this attribute in their official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In v3.0 it is `mode="lazy"` you need https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/interaction-and-ux.html#interaction-modes